# Deserialising JSON from Alamofire - Swift

Tags: json, swift, class, deserialization

I'm receiving some json via an Alamofire GET request in the following format.

```
{
  "result" : {
    "id" : 3456543
  },
  "error" : 0,
  "success" : "True"
}
```

Is there a straightforward way of iterating over this and placing the content into a class, so that I might have something like...

```
class Issues {
    var success: String?
    var error: Int?
    var resultId: Int?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using SwiftyJSON with Alamofire. There is a short example [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

But, to answer your question, for Swift 2 you can do it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mywebservice/getstuff", parameters: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value {
            let issue:Issues = Issues()
            issue.error = json["error"] as! Int
            issue.success = json["success"]
            // and so on...
        }
}
```

use this as your class:

```
//
//  Issues.swift
//
import Foundation

class Issues:NSObject
{
    var success:String?
    var error:Int?
    var resultId:Int?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak this for your particular Model, but this is the process I generally take with parsing JSON.

Model:

```
class Category : NSObject {

    // Model Objects
    var categoryId: NSNumber!
    var categoryDesc: String!
    var inAppId: String!
    var categoryUnlocked: NSNumber!

    override init() {
        self.categoryId         = 0
        self.categoryDesc       = ""
        self.inAppId            = ""
        self.categoryUnlocked   = 0
    }

    convenience init(categoryDictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.init()

        self.categoryId         = NSNumber(int: categoryDictionary["CategoryID"]!.intValue)
        self.categoryDesc       = categoryDictionary["Category_Desc"] as? String ?? ""
        self.inAppId            = categoryDictionary["InAppID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.categoryUnlocked   = categoryDictionary["CategoryUnlocked"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
    }
}
```

With the JSON I use the array.map function:

```
var categoryList = [Category]()
if let catArray = data["categories"] as? NSArray {
      categoryList = catArray.map({Category(categoryDictionary: $0 as! [String : AnyObject])})
      CoreDataService.instance.saveCategories(categoryList)
}
```

This way is tidy and readable for future developers and easily manageable within the specific Model.